# Powershell doesn't seem to get proper escaped path from $env:path

Tags: powershell, path, scala

Every time I try to execute from Powershell a command that is located in my Program Files folder (e.g. 'scala') I get this output:

```
PS C:\> scala
the term (x86) was not recognized as a cmdlet, function, executable program or script file [ecc...]
```

with the error being

```
+ C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin\scala.bat
+                   ~~~
```

I expect this is an error that comes from the space between 'Program FIles' and '(x86)'. But this is written in my PATH system variable and I have no idea how to fix this. 
How can I escape that character in order to be able to execute 'scala' (or any other command in that folder)? 
Do I have any other option?

Comment: Can you supply your PATH variable to us?  It can only be so long.

Comment: Which is exactly the reason you should update your question with the information, instead of a comment, that could get deleted.

Comment: The fact that it gripes at "(x86)" but NOT at the space between "Program" and "Files" leads me to wonder if you have two spaces instead of one, or a broken reference to "(x86)" somewhere in the path.